# node.js: output mysql (npm) pool to html or jade

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, express

We are trying to retrieve data from mysql to display it in html/jade. Unfortunately we are not able to display the records on the HTML table.

Since we are using the mysql pool, things getting more difficult. Here is our code so far. (Uses skeleton build by express generator)

/models/bew.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool = require('./databaseConnection');

var sorter = 'db.bew';
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM' + pool.escapeId(sorter);
var records = pool.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;

    // foreach
    // for(row of rows){
    //   console.log(row);
    // }

    //console.log('The fields: ', rows[0].id);
});
module.exports = records;
```

(Comment out the for-of and console.log will print the SQL rows)

routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var records = require('../models/bew');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Bewerber',
    records: records
   });

});

module.exports = router;
```

views/index.jade (html would be better)

```
extends layout

block content
  body

    table#tblBewerber
      thead
        tr
          th Name
          th Status
          th Letzte Änderung
          th Datum
          th Angelegt
          th Nächster Schritt bis
          th Nächster Schritt
          th Zul. bearbeiten
          th Bew. für
      tbody
        each record in records
          tr
            td=record.namen
```

We did several tests and it seems like the index.js doesn't get the data from 'bew.js'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I broke it down a bit to make it easier to read. 
This is how I'd solve it.

```
function sqlQuery( req, res, next ) {
    pool.query("SELECT ...", function (err, rows) {
        req.records = rows;
        next();
    })
}


router.get('/', sqlQuery, function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Bewerber',
        records: req.records
    });
});
```

This way you can split them in different files if that is what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes this is a really nice solution. Thanks for posting.

Comment: Is it possible to use more than one function inside the `router.get()` before `function(req, res, next)`?

Comment: Yes it's possible to have multiple function before the callback.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can not seperate the express router and the sql query. This is the way it worked now for us:

routes/index.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var pool = require('../models/databaseConnection');
var sql = require('../models/bew');


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  pool.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;

    res.render('index', {
      title: 'Bewerber',
      records: rows
     });
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

models/bew.js

```
var pool = require('./databaseConnection');
var sorter = 'bewerber.bewerber';
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM' + pool.escapeId(sorter);
module.exports = sql;
```

It would be nice to seperate them more we don't know a way how this could be possible.

Comment: I usually call a function before the callback from get. `router.get('/', sqlQuery, function(req, res, next) { ... })` and pass the content via `req`

Comment: @Kilian Stinson Can you maybe post an example as answer? This would help to understand better.